# How to take only uniq rows based on a column using linux cmd?

Tags: text-processing

Here is my dataset:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
a,d,f
d,u,v
f,g,h
d,u,g
x,t,k
```

Expected output:

```
f,g,h
x,t,k
```

Selection criteria:

If anything occurs in `col1` multiple times, then all of the associated rows will be deleted.

Can I solve it using Linux `sort` or `uniq` or anything else?

Comment: Welcome, in your output there is no header `col1,col2,col3`, is that meant to be?

Comment: yes, @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Comment: (1) Do lines need appear in the same order of the input file? You mention `sort` so I would think not. (2) One could suggest `sort file | uniq -uw1`, but each field isn't really just a single letter, right? In this case you gave an example but it is not complete: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option (although `awk` is better), <s>assuming the fields have no tabs in them</s><sup>1</sup>, and that you don't need to preserve the header row:

```bsh
$ tail -n+2 foo.txt | sort |
    sed 's/@/@A/g; s/\t/@B/g' |
    tr ',' '\t' | rev |
    uniq -u -f2 | rev | tr '\t' ',' |
    sed 's/@B/\t/g; s/@A/@/g'
f,g,h
x,t,k
```

- `tail -n+2` select all but the first row.
- `sort | tr ',' '\t'` sort and replace the comma for a tab to make `uniq` work.
- `rev | uniq -u -f2 | rev` reverse the lines and filter unique columns skipping the first two. Reverse to the original state.
- `tr '\t' ','` replace the tabs for commas.
- <sup>1</sup>Adding `sed 's/@/@A/g; s/\t/@B/g'` will solve the tabs issue, as suggested by @Ed Morton.

Comment: what is the issue if we don't reverse?

Comment: @RajanRaju `-f2` in unique allows to skip N *first* columns, if you don't reverse you can't skip the  2nd and 3rd, but reversing they become 1st and 2nd, hence you can skip them. So `a,b,c` becomes `c,b,a`, and `-f2` tells  `uniq` to skip `c,b` for uniqueness.

Comment: if the column contains word, then will it work?

Comment: @RajanRaju mmh, could you [edit] the question adding a testable, real example? So we can check if it would work.

Comment: got it. Actually it will work.

Comment: @RajanRaju glad to hear! But in case other solutions may appear, or to correct existing ones, adding a real example will really help, and maybe reverse downvotes or be upvoted.

Comment: I find `uniq` to be the most frustrating and inconsistent of all Unix tools. Why it doesn't have an option to specify the field separator like sort, cut, and awk do, and why it doesn't simply have a way to specify which fields to examine for uniqueness instead of just this skip N fields nonsense is just beyond me. It has it's uses of course, but it's like it was developed by people who'd never seen other Unix tools and causes us to come up with workarounds like converting commas to tabs just to make it work.

Comment: @EdMorton indeed, it seems the guys were in a hurry to develop it. Edited the answer with your suggestion (previous quick testing).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a "non-buffering"<sup>(1)</sup> two-pass approach with `awk` (will only work on regular files).

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++;next} FNR>1&&cnt[$1]==1' input.csv input.csv
```

This will process the file twice, hence it is stated twice as argument on the command-line.

- The argument `-F','` sets the field separator to be `,`.
- In the first pass, when `NR`, the global line counter, is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, we register how often each value in column 1 is encountered in an array `cnt` (which takes the value as "array index"), but immediately skip processing to the next line.
- In the second pass, we check if the occurence counter for the current value of the first column is exactly 1, and the line number within the file is greater than 1 (to skip the header). Only if that is true will the current line be printed. This makes use of the `awk` syntax that an expression outside of rule blocks that evaluates to `true` instructs `awk` to print the current line.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> In reaction to a comment I placed *non-buffering* in quotes, because since the solution will store some data from the file temporarily in the RAM, it *does* come with RAM usage. However it will not store the file content verbatim *in addition* to any other scroll-keeping data in RAM (which *I* would consider "buffering" in the actual sense).

Comment: it actually buffers the first column of the file in first pass, so cannot say non-buffer

Comment: @αғsнιη Well, you could argue about that. I would only consider it "buffering" if the program stored the 1st column verbatim (i.e. all entries in the 1st column, in order). But the proposed program only registers occurence counts in an array, which implies at least deduplication. I would't really call that "buffering" ...

Comment: LGTM, I previously upvoted FWIW. There's always someone running around downvoting for no reason.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, I somewhat suspected that it was the casual "drive-by downvoter" who wouldn't care to supply constructive criticism (I saw your answer also received one of those ...). But I haven't given up hope yet that someday one of them might actually react ;)

Comment: I have a particular fan who complained to the mods about me providing constructive feedback on their answers (just like I do for everyone if I think it'd be useful) as they think I'm picking on them, I'm pretty sure that's who downvotes most of my answers and I wouldn't be surprised if they extend that same courtesy to others who've also tried to help them in the past. If I could spend SE points I'd worry about it :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Haha, wouldn't that be a great feature - and it might make more sense than many crypto-currencies ... :)

Comment: @EdMorton The opposite also happens... apparently somebody "liked" me, and one day I got ten answers upvoted, but the system is aware of massive upvotes and they were canceled.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity right, it catches people up or down voting many answers in a day but AFAIK it doesn't catch someone up or down voting almost every answer you post once or twice a day over a long period of time. I did one time contact the mods about someone doing that and after a lot of back-and-forth, eventually they investigated, admitted it was 1 person, and took action to reverse all their downvotes. In doing so they also found someone upvoting my answers more than they thought appropriate and reversed all of those too so the net impact to me was that I lost votes overall. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the file is `/tmp/data` you can do it with a perl one-liner:

`perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { /(^\S+?),/; $show->{$1}=$_; $count->{$1}++;}; foreach(keys %$show) {print $show->{$_} if($count->{$_} == 1);}' < /tmp/data`

Or more readable... :

```perl
while(<STDIN>) { #loop through all lines in the input and put the lines in "$_"
  /(^\S+?),/; #Everything before the first "," now ends up in "$1"
  $show->{$1} = $_; #a hash will be created with as keys the "$1" and as values the "$_"
  $count->{$1}++; #In the hash $count the number of occurrences will be increased everytime the same $1 appears
}
foreach(keys %$show) { #loop trough all lines
  print $show->{$_} if($count->{$_} == 1); #only print them if they occur once
}
```

Comment: I would have used the -n switch and the }{ operator to shorten it to
perl -ne '/(^\S+?),/; $show->{$1}=$_; $count->{$1}++; }{ foreach (keys %$show) {print $show->{$_} if ($count->{$_} == 1);}' /tmp/data

Answer (score 5):

`awk` only solution

1. not keeping order

   ```
   awk -F, 'NR>1 { count[$1]++ ; line[$1]=$0 ;} 
      END { for ( c in count) if (count[c] ==1) print line[c]}' data
   ```
2. keeping order

   ```
   awk -F, 'NR>1 { row[a]=$0; col[a]=$1; count[$1]++; ++a; } 
      END { for (i=0; i<a; ++i) if (count[col[i]]==1) print row[i]; }' data
   ```

where

- `-F,` tell awk to use `,` as separator
- `NR>1`  after first line
- `count[$1]++` count element of first column
- `line[$1]=$0`  store line
- `END` after end of file
- `for ( c in count)` loop through element
- `if (count[c] ==1)` if only one
- `print line[c]` print line
- `a` and `col[]` are used to store order of line in order preserving variant.

this can be onelined, I fold for readability

Comment: The one thing I found testing it is that it reverses the sorting, i.e.: `x,t,k
f,g,h`, not `f,g,h
x,t,k`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it doesn't reverse the order, it prints the lines in "random" order courtesy of the `in` operator, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array. So you could get the input order, or you could get it reversed or you could get any other order of output.

Comment: To preserve order use something like: `awk -F, 'NR>1 { row[a]=$0; col[a]=$1; count[$1]++; ++a; } END { for (i=0; i<a; ++i) if (count[col[i]]==1) print row[i]; }' data`

Comment: @PaulEvans thanks I updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

decorate/sort/use/undecorate using any version of the mandatory POSIX tools and any characters in your input (unless your input is actually a CSV with quoted fields that can contain commas and/or newlines but then all other answers would fail too) and retaining the order of input lines for the output and only opening the input once so it'll work if the input is coming from a pipe or a file and without storing  the whole input in memory:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{print ++cnt[$1], NR, $0}' file |
    sort -nt, -k1,1r -k2,2 |
    awk -F, '(!seen[$3]++) && ($1==1)' |
    cut -d, -f3-
f,g,h
x,t,k
```

Answer (score 3):

This removes the first line (`col1,col2,col3`) and always outputs the lines in the same order as the input:

```
perl -nlE'/.*?,/;$.-1&&push@a,[$&,$_];$a{$&}++;say$$_[1] for grep$a{$$_[0]}<2&eof,@a' data
```

Answer (score 3):

This uses `bash` and BSD `sed` and may require tweaking for non-Berkeley systems:

```
$ cat << EOF > input
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
a,d,f
d,u,v
f,g,h
d,u,g
x,t,k
EOF
$ grep -f <(sed -Ee '1d;s/([^,]*),.*/^\1,/' < input | sort | uniq -u ) input
f,g,h
x,t,k
```

This works by first using `sed` to delete line 1 of the input file `input`, and then writing the first comma-delimited field of each line, preceded by a `^` and followed by a `,`.  That `sed` output is then `sort`ed and `uniq`ed so that only the lines that have no duplicates appear in the output.  The output of `uniq` is then passed to `grep` and used as a series of regular expressions to search for in the input file.

This solution will likely break if your input file contains certain regular expression meta-characters in the first column.

Answer (score 1):

- Order does not matter

```
awk -F "," '
{
  a[$1] = $1 in a ? "" : ($0 ORS)
}
END {
  for (i in a) printf "%s", a[i]
}
' file
```

---

- Order is same as input

```
awk -F "," '
{
  if ($1 in a) a[$1] = ORS
  else a[b[++k]=$1] = $0 RS
}
END {
  while(++i in b) print a[b[i]]
}
' ORS= file
```

Answer (score 1):

- GNU sed with extended regex support (-E)

```
sed -Ee ':b;$!{N;bb;}
/^(([^,]+,).*)\n\2[^\n]+/!{P;D;}
  :a;s//\1/;ta;D
' file
```

- slurp the file into pattern space.
- so long as the first line in pattern space has no match of its first field anywhere (meaning it is unique) it is printed and clipped.
- otherwise, meaning the first line first field found a match in subsequent lines we delete all such lines.

---

itertools method groupby is used to group on sorted on first field and then groups containing a single element are selected.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it

## anonymous function defined here
Gx = lambda fh,col: it.groupby(sorted(fh,key=col),col)
k1 = lambda x: x.split(",")[0]
fx = lambda t: "".join(t[1])
gx = lambda y: y.count("\n") == 1

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
 
 print(*filter(gx,map(fx,Gx(f,k1))),sep="",end="")
' file
```

---

```
awk -F "," '
BEGIN { s[1] = ORS }
{
  sep = s[$1 in a]
  a[$1] = a[$1] sep sprintf("%dd",NR)
}
END {
  for (var in a)
    if (split(a[var],t,ORS) >= 2)
      print a[var]
}
' < file | sed -f - file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
    ~$ raku -e ' \
    my @csv_array   = $*ARGFILES.lines.skip(1).map: *.split(",");  \
    my $col1        = @csv_array.map( *.[ 0,3...*]);  \
    my @col1_nodups = $col1.cache.Bag.grep( *.value == 1).map: *.keys;  \
    $_.join(",").put  for @csv_array[ $col1.grep(/@col1_nodups/, :k)];'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
a,d,f
d,u,v
f,g,h
d,u,g
x,t,k
```

Sample Output:

```
f,g,h
x,t,k
```

Even though the word "uniq" appears in the title of this question, the OP is not asking for a return of rows based upon *distinct* values within column 1, but rather to remove ALL rows with *duplicate* values in column 1 (not de-duplication, but elimination).

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. :

- The four lines of code above can be pasted into the bash command line, with the target `file` given (as shown above) to achieve the desired results.
- Alternatively, the four lines of code saved into a script such as `return_singleton_rows_only.p6`. Change the first line `$*ARGFILES` to  `"/path/to/csv_file.txt".IO`, and remove the end-of-line (continuation) backslashes. The script can then be executed at the bash prompt with `~$ raku return_singleton_rows_only.p6` .
- Alternative (2), keeping the first line `$*ARGFILES` as-is, you can save the four lines of code into a script such as `return_singleton_rows_only.p6` (removing the end-of-line continuation backslashes), add an appropriate `#!` shebang line at top (such as `#!/usr/bin/env raku`), and make the file executable. Then run at the command line `~$ return_singleton_rows_only.p6 file` .

Briefly, line 1 reads the `csv_file` into a Raku array called `@csv_array`, splitting on "`,`" (commas), and skipping the header line. Line 2 extracts column 1 into a scalar list called `$col1`. Line 3 removes any value present in `$col1` by `Bag`-ging and only keeping `*.keys` which have `*.value == 1`. Finally, line 4 subsets the original `@csv_array` using an index created by `grep`-ping out the row number of desired rows.

[I'm sure there are more efficient approaches, but this code has the advantage of 1). reading `lines` lazily, and 2). having singleton values available as a separate array object `@col1_nodups`, should they be needed for further data manipulation].

https://raku.org